# text/css transferred as text/plain

Tags: css, mime-types, plaintext

I have a webpage that is transferring A stylesheet as a text/plain MIME type. what are the possible reasons for this to occur and any tips on how to resolve that problem.

im linking the css like this

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

Comment: How are you serving this file?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Try to read your question as an ousider, someone who is not familiar with you, your code or anything related. Try to give as much information as you can, for example some code. This way you are more likely to recieve meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server misconfiguration. This could depend on an overall configuration error, or on something more limited, like a badly written `.htaccess` file in the `css` directory, if the server is running Apache.